# Stored Procedure RAISERROR - Transaction Count Msg Returned

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction, error-handling

I have a stored procedure that should return the below `RAISERROR` message when called. However, the text is appended to the message when returned:

```
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of 
BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0
```

Why is this? Is the statement order in the `CATCH` block correct?

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON; -- ensures the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back. **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN --all as one transaction.

    IF EXISTS(
            SELECT 
                SupervisorID
            FROM [dbo].[UserDetail]
            WHERE
                SupervisorID IS NOT NULL
            )
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR('Unable to alter a approved data.', 18, 1)    
    END
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Determine if an error occurred.  
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK;

    -- Return the error information. 
    DECLARE 
        @error_number AS INT,
        @error_message AS NVARCHAR(1000),
        @error_severity AS INT;
    SELECT
        @error_number=ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @error_message=ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @error_severity=ERROR_SEVERITY();
    RAISERROR(@error_message,@error_severity,1);

END CATCH
```

Comment: If I run the exact code above (albeit changing your `IF EXISTS` to an `IF 1 <> 0`), it works and raises the correct error. Is there something you're not showing us?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the "Transaction count mismatch" error if you have an open transaction prior to enter this stored procedure. The problem is that `BEGIN TRAN` will increment `@@TRANCOUNT` by 1 each time it is called, and `COMMIT` will decrement by 1 each time it is called, yet `ROLLBACK` will always reset back to 0 since there truly is no such thing as a nested transaction in SQL Server.

In your case, you have an active transaction before this stored procedure is called, but the `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH` block resets `@@TRANCOUNT` back to 0, hence the error.

The trick to handling nested stored procedures, each having their own error handling, is to *not* call `BEGIN TRAN` if you are already in an active transaction (it doesn't do anything anyway outside of open you up to the possibility of getting this error ;-). The template that I prefer using is found in the following answer of mine, also here on DBA.SE:

[Are we required to handle Transaction in C# Code as well as in stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93258/are-we-required-to-handle-transaction-in-c-code-as-well-as-in-stored-procedure/93265#93265)