# In what cases a transaction can be committed from inside the CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is set to ON?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been reading MSDN about [`TRY...CATCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175976.aspx) and [`XACT_STATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189797.aspx).

It has the following example that uses `XACT_STATE` in the `CATCH` block of a `TRY…CATCH` construct to determine whether to commit or roll back a transaction:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will render the transaction uncommittable
-- when the constraint violation occurs.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This 
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.
        DELETE FROM Production.Product
            WHERE ProductID = 980;

    -- If the delete operation succeeds, commit the transaction. The CATCH
    -- block will not execute.
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Test XACT_STATE for 0, 1, or -1.
    -- If 1, the transaction is committable.
    -- If -1, the transaction is uncommittable and should 
    --     be rolled back.
    -- XACT_STATE = 0 means there is no transaction and
    --     a commit or rollback operation would generate an error.

    -- Test whether the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state.' +
              ' Rolling back transaction.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

    -- Test whether the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The transaction is committable.' + 
              ' Committing transaction.'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
    END;
END CATCH;
GO
```

What I don't understand is, why should I care and check what `XACT_STATE` returns?

**Please note, that the flag [`XACT_ABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188792.aspx) is set to `ON` in the example.**

If there is a severe enough error inside the `TRY` block, the control will pass into `CATCH`. So, if I'm inside the `CATCH`, I know that transaction has had a problem and really the only sensible thing to do in this case is to roll it back, isn't it?

But, this example from MSDN implies that there can be cases when control is passed into `CATCH` and still it makes sense to commit the transaction. Could somebody provide some practical example when it can happen, when it makes sense?

I don't see in what cases the control can be passed inside `CATCH` with a transaction that can be committed **when `XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON`**.

MSDN article about [`SET XACT_ABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188792.aspx) has an example when some statements inside a transaction execute successfully and some fail when `XACT_ABORT` is set to `OFF`, I understand that. But, with `SET XACT_ABORT ON` how can it happen that `XACT_STATE()` returns 1 inside the `CATCH` block?

Initially, I would have written this code like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will render the transaction uncommittable
-- when the constraint violation occurs.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This 
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.
        DELETE FROM Production.Product
            WHERE ProductID = 980;

    -- If the delete operation succeeds, commit the transaction. The CATCH
    -- block will not execute.
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Some severe problem with the transaction
    PRINT 'Rolling back transaction.';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
GO
```

---

Taking into account an answer by Max Vernon, I would write the code like this. He showed that it makes sense to check whether there is an active transaction before attempting to `ROLLBACK`. Still, with `SET XACT_ABORT ON` the `CATCH` block can have either doomed transaction or no transaction at all. So, in any case there is nothing to `COMMIT`. Am I wrong?

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- SET XACT_ABORT ON will render the transaction uncommittable
-- when the constraint violation occurs.
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- A FOREIGN KEY constraint exists on this table. This 
        -- statement will generate a constraint violation error.
        DELETE FROM Production.Product
            WHERE ProductID = 980;

    -- If the delete operation succeeds, commit the transaction. The CATCH
    -- block will not execute.
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Some severe problem with the transaction
    IF (XACT_STATE()) <> 0
    BEGIN
        -- There is still an active transaction that should be rolled back
        PRINT 'Rolling back transaction.';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;

END CATCH;
GO
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that transaction can **not** be committed from inside the `CATCH` block if `XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON`.

The example from MSDN is somewhat misleading, because the check implies that `XACT_STATE` can return 1 in some cases and it may be possible to `COMMIT` the transaction.

```
IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'The transaction is committable.' + 
          ' Committing transaction.'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
END;
```

It is not true, `XACT_STATE` will never return 1 inside `CATCH` block if `XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON`.

It seems that the MSDN sample code was meant to primarily illustrate the use of `XACT_STATE()` function regardless of the `XACT_ABORT` setting.
The sample code looks generic enough to work with both `XACT_ABORT` set to `ON` and `OFF`.
It is just that with `XACT_ABORT = ON` the check `IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1` becomes unnecessary.

---

There is a very good detailed set of articles about [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) by Erland Sommarskog.
In [Part 2 - Classification of Errors](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) he presents a comprehensive table 
that puts together all classes of errors and how they are handled by SQL Server and how `TRY ... CATCH` and `XACT_ABORT` changes the behaviour.

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------------++------------------------------+
|                             |     Without TRY-CATCH     ||        With TRY-CATCH        |
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----++------------------+-----+-----+
|              SET XACT_ABORT |  OFF  |  ON   | OFF | ON  ||    ON or OFF     | OFF | ON  |
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----++------------------+-----+-----+
| Class Name                  |    Aborts     |   Rolls   ||    Catchable     |   Dooms   |
|                             |               |   Back    ||                  |transaction|
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----++------------------+-----+-----+
| Fatal errors                |  Connection   |    Yes    ||       No         |    n/a    |
| Batch-aborting              |     Batch     |    Yes    ||       Yes        |    Yes    |
| Batch-only aborting         |     Batch     | No  | Yes ||       Yes        | No  | Yes |
| Statement-terminating       | Stmnt | Batch | No  | Yes ||       Yes        | No  | Yes |
| Terminates nothing at all   |    Nothing    |    No     ||       Yes        | No  | Yes |
| Compilation: syntax errors  |  (Statement)  |    No     ||       Yes        | No  | Yes |
| Compilation: binding errors | Scope | Batch | No  | Yes || Outer scope only | No  | Yes |
| Compilation: optimisation   |     Batch     |    Yes    || Outer scope only |    Yes    |
| Attention signal            |     Batch     | No  | Yes ||       No         |    n/a    |
| Informational/warning msgs  |    Nothing    |    No     ||       No         |    n/a    |
| Uncatchable errors          |    Varying    |  Varying  ||       No         |    n/a    |
+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-----+-----++------------------+-----+-----+
```

The last column in the table answers the question. With `TRY-CATCH` and with `XACT_ABORT ON` the transaction is doomed in all possible cases.

One note outside the scope of the question. As Erland says, this consistency is one of the reasons to set `XACT_ABORT` to `ON`:

> I have already given the recommendation that your stored procedures
>   should include the command `SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON`.  If you look
>   at the table above, you see that with `XACT_ABORT` in effect, there is
>   some higher level of consistency.  For instance, the transaction is
>   always doomed.  In the following, I will show many examples where I
>   set `XACT_ABORT` to `OFF`, so that you can get an understanding of why
>   you should avoid this default setting.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR / Executive Summary:** Regarding this part of the Question:

> I don't see in what cases the control can be passed inside `CATCH` with a transaction that can be committed **when `XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON`**.

I have done quite a bit of testing on this now and I cannot find any cases where `XACT_STATE()` returns `1` inside of a `CATCH` block when `@@TRANCOUNT > 0` *and* the session property of `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`. And in fact, according to the current MSDN page for [SET XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

That statement appears to be in agreement with your speculation and my findings.

> MSDN article about `SET XACT_ABORT` has an example when some statements inside a transaction execute successfully and some fail when `XACT_ABORT` is set to `OFF`

True, *but* the statements in that example are *not* within a `TRY` block. Those same statements within a `TRY` block would still prevent execution for any statements after the one that caused the error, but assuming that `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF`, when control is passed to the `CATCH` block the Transaction is still physically valid in that all of the prior changes did happen without error and *can* be committed, if that is the desire, *or* they can be rolled-back. On the other hand, if `XACT_ABORT` is `ON` then any prior changes are automatically rolled-back, and *then* you are given the choice to either: a) issue a `ROLLBACK` which is mostly just an acceptance of the situation since the Transaction was already rolled back minus resetting `@@TRANCOUNT` to `0`, or b) get an error. Not much of a choice, is it?

One possibly important detail to this puzzle that is not apparent in that documentation for `SET XACT_ABORT` is that this session property, and that example code even, has been around since [SQL Server 2000](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259192.aspx) (the documentation is nearly identical between the versions), predating the `TRY...CATCH` construct which was introduced in SQL Server 2005. Looking at that documentation again and looking at the example (*without* the `TRY...CATCH`), using `XACT_ABORT ON` causes an *immediate* roll-back of the Transaction: there is no Transaction state of "uncommittable" (please note that there is no mention at all of an "uncommittable" Transaction state in that `SET XACT_ABORT` documentation).

I think it is reasonable to conclude that:

1. the introduction of the `TRY...CATCH` construct in SQL Server 2005 created the need for a new Transaction state (i.e. "uncommittable") and the `XACT_STATE()` function to get that information.
2. checking `XACT_STATE()` in a `CATCH` block really only makes sense if both of the following are true:
3. `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF` (else `XACT_STATE()` should always return `-1` and `@@TRANCOUNT` would be all you need)
4. You have logic in the `CATCH` block, or somewhere up the chain if the calls are nested, that makes a change (a `COMMIT` or even any DML, DDL, etc statement) *instead of* doing a `ROLLBACK`. (this is a very atypical use case)
   ** please see note at the bottom, in the UPDATE 3 section, regarding an unofficial recommendation by Microsoft to always check `XACT_STATE()` instead of `@@TRANCOUNT`, and why testing shows that their reasoning does not pan out.
5. the introduction of the `TRY...CATCH` construct in SQL Server 2005 has, for the most part, obsoleted the `XACT_ABORT ON` session property as it provides for a greater degree of control over the Transaction (you at least have the option to `COMMIT`, provided that `XACT_STATE()` does not return `-1`).
   Another way to look at this is, *prior to SQL Server 2005*, `XACT_ABORT ON` provided an easy and reliable way to stop processing when an error occurred, as compared to checking `@@ERROR` after each statement.
6. The documentation example code for `XACT_STATE()` is erroneous, or at best misleading, in that it shows checking for `XACT_STATE() = 1` when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`.

---

**The long part ;-)**

Yes, that example code on MSDN is a bit confusing (see also: [@@TRANCOUNT (Rollback) vs. XACT_STATE](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/trancount-rollback-vs-xact_state)) ;-). And, I  feel it is misleading because it either shows something that makes no sense (for the reason that you are asking about: can you even have a "committable" transaction in the `CATCH` block when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`), or even if it is possible, it still focuses on a technical possibility that few will ever want or need, and ignores the reason one is more likely to need it.

> If there is a severe enough error inside the TRY block, the control will pass into CATCH. So, if I'm inside the CATCH, I know that transaction has had a problem and really the only sensible thing to do in this case is to roll it back, isn't it?

I think it would help if we made sure that we are on the same page regarding what is meant by certain words and concepts:

- **"severe enough error":** Just to be clear, [TRY...CATCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) will trap most errors. The list of what will not be caught is listed on that linked MSDN page, under the "Errors Unaffected by a TRY…CATCH Construct" section.
- **"if I'm inside the CATCH, I know that *transaction* has had a problem" (em*phas*is added):** If by "transaction" you mean the *logical* unit of work as determined by you by grouping statements into an explicit transaction, then most likely yes. I think most of us DB folks would tend to agree that rolling-back is "the only sensible thing to do" since we likely have a similar view of how and why we use explicit transactions and conceive of what steps should make up an atomic unit of work.

  But, if you mean the *actual* units of work that are being grouped into the explicit transaction, then no, you don't know that the transaction itself has had a problem. You only know that *a* statement executing within the explicitly defined transaction has raised an error. But it might not be a DML or DDL statement. And even if it was a DML statement, the Transaction itself might still be committable.

Given the two points made above, we should probably draw a distinction between transactions that you "can't" commit, and ones that you "don't want" to commit.

When `XACT_STATE()` returns a `1`, that means that the Transaction is "committable", that you have a choice between `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. You might not *want* to commit it, but if for some hard-to-even-come-up-with-an-example-for reason you wanted to, at least you could because some parts of the Transaction did complete successfully.

But when `XACT_STATE()` returns a `-1`, then you really need to `ROLLBACK` because some part of the Transaction went into a bad state. Now, I do agree that if control has been passed to the CATCH block, then it makes sense enough to just check `@@TRANCOUNT`, because even if you could commit the Transaction, why would you want to?

But if you notice at the top of the example, the setting of `XACT_ABORT ON` changes things a bit. You can have a regular error, after doing `BEGIN TRAN` that will pass control to the CATCH block when `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF` and XACT_STATE() will return `1`. BUT, if XACT_ABORT is `ON`, then the Transaction is "aborted" (i.e. invalidated) for any 'ol error and then `XACT_STATE()` will return `-1`. In this case, it seems useless to check `XACT_STATE()` within the `CATCH` block as it always seems to return a `-1` when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`.

So then what is `XACT_STATE()` for? Some clues are:

- MSDN page for `TRY...CATCH`, under the "Uncommittable Transactions and XACT_STATE" section, says:

  > An error that ordinarily ends a transaction outside a TRY block causes a transaction to enter an uncommittable state when the error occurs inside a TRY block.
- The MSDN page for [SET XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx), under the "Remarks" section, says:

  > When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing.

  and:

  > XACT_ABORT must be set ON for data modification statements in an implicit or explicit transaction against most OLE DB providers, including SQL Server.
- The MSDN page for [BEGIN TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx), under the "Remarks" section, says:

  > The local transaction started by the BEGIN TRANSACTION statement is escalated to a distributed transaction if the following actions are performed before the statement is committed or rolled back:
  >
  > - An INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement that references a remote table on a linked server is executed. The INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement fails if the OLE DB provider used to access the linked server does not support the ITransactionJoin interface.

The most applicable usage seems to be within the context of Linked Server DML statements. And I believe I ran into this myself years ago. I don't remember all of the details, but it had something to do with the remote server not being available, and for some reason, that error did not get caught within the TRY block and never got sent to the CATCH and so it did a COMMIT when it shouldn't have. Of course, that *could* have been an issue of not having `XACT_ABORT` set to `ON` rather than failing to check `XACT_STATE()`, or possibly both. And I do recall reading something that said if you use Linked Servers and/or Distributed Transactions then you needed to use `XACT_ABORT ON` and/or `XACT_STATE()`, but I cannot seem to find that document now. If I do find it, I will update this with the link.

Still, I have tried several things and am unable to find a scenario that has `XACT_ABORT ON` and passes control to the `CATCH` block with `XACT_STATE()` reporting `1`.

Try these examples to see the effect of `XACT_ABORT` on the value of `XACT_STATE()`:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

    SELECT 1/0 AS [DivideByZero]; -- error, yo!

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [@@TRANCOUNT],
            XACT_STATE() AS [XactState],
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage]

    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END CATCH;

GO ------------------------------------------------

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

    SELECT 1/0 AS [DivideByZero]; -- error, yo!

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [@@TRANCOUNT],
            XACT_STATE() AS [XactState],
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage]

    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END CATCH;

GO ------------------------------------------------

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1/0 AS [DivideByZero]; -- error, yo!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [@@TRANCOUNT],
            XACT_STATE() AS [XactState],
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage]
END CATCH;
```

---

**UPDATE**

While not part of the original Question, based on these comments on this Answer:

> I've been reading through Erland's articles on [Error and Transaction Handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) where he says that `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF` by default for legacy reasons and normally we should set it to `ON`.
> ...
> "... if you follow the recommendation and run with SET XACT_ABORT ON, the transaction will always be doomed."

Prior to using `XACT_ABORT ON` everywhere, I would question: what exactly is being gained here? I have not found it necessary to do and generally advocate that you should use it only when necessary. Whether or not you want to `ROLLBACK` can be handle easily enough by using the template shown in @Remus's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128558/30859), or the one that I have been using for years that is essentially the same thing but without the Save Point, as shown in this answer (which handles nested calls):

[Are we required to handle Transaction in C# Code as well as in stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93258/are-we-required-to-handle-transaction-in-c-code-as-well-as-in-store-procedure/93265#93265)

---

**UPDATE 2**

I did a bit more testing, this time by creating a small .NET Console App, creating a Transaction in the app layer, prior to executing any `SqlCommand` objects (i.e. via `using (SqlTransaction _Tran = _Connection.BeginTransaction()) { ...` ), as well as using a batch-aborting error instead of just a statement-aborting error, and found that:

1. An "uncommitable" Transaction is one that has been, for the most part, rolled back already (the changes have been undone), but `@@TRANCOUNT` is still > 0.
2. When you have an "uncommitable" Transaction you cannot issue a `COMMIT` as that will generate and error saying that the Transaction is "uncommittable". You also cannot ignore it / do nothing as an error will be generated when the batch finishes stating that the batch completed with a lingering, uncommittable transaction and it will be rolled back (so, um, if it will auto-roll-back anyway, why bother throwing the error?). So you *must* issue an explicit `ROLLBACK`, maybe not in the immediate `CATCH` block, but before the batch ends.
3. In a `TRY...CATCH` construct, when `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF`, errors that would terminate the Transaction automatically had they occurred outside of a `TRY` block, such as batch-aborting errors, will undo the work but not terminate the Tranasction, leaving it as "uncommitable". Issuing a `ROLLBACK` is more of a formality needed to close out the Transaction, but the work has already been rolled-back.
4. When `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`, most errors act as batch-aborting, and hence behave as described in the bullet point directly above (#3).
5. `XACT_STATE()`, at least in a `CATCH` block, will show a `-1` for batch-aborting errors if there was an active Transaction at the time of the error.
6. `XACT_STATE()` sometimes returns `1` even when there is no active Transaction. If `@@SPID` (among others) is in the `SELECT` list along with `XACT_STATE()`, then `XACT_STATE()` will return 1 when there is no active Transaction. This behavior started in SQL Server 2012, and exists on 2014, but I haven't tested on 2016.

With the above points in mind:

- Given points #4 and #5, since most (or all?) errors will render a Transaction "uncommitable", it seems entirely pointless to check `XACT_STATE()` in the `CATCH` block when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON` since the value returned will always be `-1`.
- Checking `XACT_STATE()` in the `CATCH` block when `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF` makes more sense because the return value will at least have some variation since it will return `1` for statement-aborting errors. However, if you code like most of us, then this distinction is meaningless since you will be calling `ROLLBACK` anyway simply for the fact that an error occurred.
- If you find a situation that does warrant issuing a `COMMIT` in the `CATCH` block, *then* check the value of `XACT_STATE()`, and be sure to `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;`.
- `XACT_ABORT ON` seems to offer little to no benefit over the `TRY...CATCH` construct.
- I can find no scenario where checking `XACT_STATE()` provides a meaningful benefit over simply checking `@@TRANCOUNT`.
- I can also find no scenario where `XACT_STATE()` returns `1` in a `CATCH` block when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`. I think it is a documentation error.
- Yes, you can roll-back a Transaction that you did not explicitly begin. And in the context of using `XACT_ABORT ON`, it's a moot point since an error happening in a `TRY` block will automatically roll-back the changes.
- The `TRY...CATCH` construct has the benefit over `XACT_ABORT ON` in not automatically cancelling the whole Transaction, and hence allowing the Transaction (as long as `XACT_STATE()` returns `1`) to be committed (even if this is an edge-case).

Example of `XACT_STATE()` returning `-1` when `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF`:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;

    SELECT CONVERT(INT, 'g') AS [ConversionError];

    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @State INT;
    SET @State = XACT_STATE();
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [@@TRANCOUNT],
            @State AS [XactState],
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage];

    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Rollin back...' AS [Transaction];
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END CATCH;
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

Related to item #6 in the UPDATE 2 section (i.e. possible incorrect value returned by `XACT_STATE()` when there is no active Transaction):

- The odd / erroneous behavior started in SQL Server 2012 (so far tested against 2012 SP2 and 2014 SP1)
- In SQL Server versions 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2, `XACT_STATE()` did not report expected values when used in Triggers or `INSERT...EXEC` scenarios: [xact_state() cannot be used reliably to determine whether a transaction is doomed](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://connect.microsoft.com:80/SQLServer/feedback/details/411709/xact-state-cannot-be-used-reliably-to-determine-whether-a-transaction-is-doomed) <sup>(archived page)</sup>. However, in these 3 versions (I only tested on 2008 R2), `XACT_STATE()` does *not* incorrectly report `1` when used in a `SELECT` with `@@SPID`.
- There <del>is</del> *was* a Connect bug filed against the behavior mentioned here but is closed as "By Design": *XACT_STATE() can return an incorrect transaction state in SQL 2012* <sup>(link no longer valid due to incompetent and/or grossly negligent site migration )</sup>. However, the test was done when selecting from a DMV and it was concluded that doing so would naturally have a system generated transaction, at least for some DMVs. It was also stated in the final response by MS that:

  > Note that an IF statement, and also a SELECT without FROM, do not start a transaction.
  > for example, running SELECT XACT_STATE() if you don't have a previously existing transaction will return 0.

  Those statements are incorrect given the following example:

  ```sql
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [TRANCOUNT], XACT_STATE() AS [XACT_STATE], @@SPID AS [SPID];
    GO
    DECLARE @SPID INT;
    SET @SPID = @@SPID;
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [TRANCOUNT], XACT_STATE() AS [XACT_STATE], @SPID AS [SPID];
    GO
  ```
- Hence, I filed a new Feedback bug:
  [XACT_STATE() returns 1 when used in SELECT with some system variables but without FROM clause](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32900548-xact-state-returns-1-when-used-in-select-with-so)

PLEASE NOTE that in the "XACT_STATE() can return an incorrect transaction state in SQL 2012" Connect item linked directly above, Microsoft (well, a representative of) states:

> @@trancount returns the number of BEGIN TRAN statements. It is thus not a reliable indicator of whether there is an active transaction. XACT_STATE() also returns 1 if there is an active autocommit transaction, and is thus a more reliable indicator of whether there is an active transaction.

However, I can find no reason to not trust `@@TRANCOUNT`. The following test shows that `@@TRANCOUNT` does indeed return `1` in an auto-commit transaction:

```sql
--- begin setup
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #TransactionInfo AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT AS [TranCount],
       XACT_STATE() AS [XactState];
GO
--- end setup

DECLARE @Test TABLE (TranCount INT, XactState INT);

SELECT * FROM @Test; -- no rows

EXEC #TransactionInfo; -- 0 for both fields

INSERT INTO @Test (TranCount, XactState)
    EXEC #TransactionInfo;

SELECT * FROM @Test; -- 1 row; 1 for both fields
```

I also tested on a real table with a Trigger and `@@TRANCOUNT` within the Trigger did accurately report `1` even though no explicit Transaction had been started.

Answer (score 7):

I would approach this differently. `XACT_ABORT_ON` is a sledge hammer, you can use a more refined approach, see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
go
```

This approach will rollback, when possible, only the work performed inside the TRY block, and restore state to the state before entering the TRY block. This way you can do complex processing, like iterating a cursor, w/o loosing all the work in case of an error. The only draw back is that, by using transaction savepoints, you are restricted from using anything that is incompatible with savepoints, like distributed transactions.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but the question is not really whether we should set `XACT_ABORT` to `ON` or `OFF`.

Answer (score 5):

Defensive programing requires you to write code that handles as many known states as possible, thereby reducing the possibility of bugs.

Checking XACT_STATE() to determine if a rollback can be executed is simply a good practice.  Blindly attempting a rollback means you may inadvertently cause an error inside your TRY...CATCH.

One way a rollback might fail inside a TRY...CATCH would be if you didn't explicitly start a transaction.  Copy and pasting code blocks might easily cause this.