# Nested stored procedures with use of transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question regarding this tsql-code found in this thread regarding "nested transactions" (unfortunately my reputation is not large enough to comment in that thread):
[In what cases a transaction can be committed from inside the CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is set to ON?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128535/in-what-cases-a-transaction-can-be-committed-from-inside-the-catch-block-when-xa?newreg=4ab1357c6bb14c30acb4b8036fa66fbd)

Here is a procedure with transactions-check and a savepoint if the @@trancount > 0
But I don't see the difference the savepoint makes, when there is a "raiserror-statement" in the catch block of the procedure. Will this not force the calling code to rollback to the beginning of the calling code, thus ignoring the savepoint?

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Insert into table:
           INSERT INTO TABLE1 'Data from usp_my_procedure_name'

        -- Make an error:
           SELECT 1/0

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
go
```

If this procedure is called in a nested way like this

```
CREATE OuterProc AS
    BEGIN TRY
     BEGIN TRANSACTION

     INSERT INTO TABLE1 'Data from OuterProc code'

     EXEC usp_my_procedure_name 

     COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
END
```

If I execute the OuterProc, the data 'Data from OuterProc code' will not get inserted.
Then what is the point of the savepoint?

It works if I remove the raiserror-part of the code. Then the 'Data from OuterProc code' gets inserted..

So my question is - what is the point of the savepoint when there is a raiserror-statement in the procedures catch-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first get the `RAISERRROR()` part out of the way, more specifically why does the insert happen when it is removed.

> It works if I remove the raiserror-part of the code. Then the 'Data
>   from OuterProc code' gets inserted..

The raise error is defined outside of the `TRY` block scope

```
    raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
```

And the documentation shows that the error is returned to the caller (`OuterProc`) when `RAISERROR()` is ran outside of the try block scope.

> The error is returned to the caller if RAISERROR is run:
>
> Outside the scope of any TRY block.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

As a result, the raiserror returns control to the `OuterProc` procedure, and as a result of the error happening in the TRY block of the outer procedure it is returned to the `CATCH` block. And, inside this catch block is a ROLLBACK.

**-->**  `ROLLBACK`

If you add this to the CATCH block of the outer proc:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
    select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();

raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
 ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

The error gets re-raised:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OuterProc, Line 17 [Batch
>   Start Line 58] usp_my_procedure_name: 50000: usp_my_procedure_name:
>   8134: Divide by zero error encountered.

And the outer proc insert:

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 
 VALUES('Data from OuterProc code')
```

Gets rolled back.

---

> So my question is - what is the point of the savepoint when there is a
>   raiserror-statement in the procedures catch-block

The savepoint is there to not rollback the entire transaction, but due to your use of `TRY CATCH` in the outer procedure, your outer procedure is also rolled back.

If you don't want the outer transaction to also be rolled back, then you should not use an additional `TRY CATCH` block around the outer transaction.

You would have to define the procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OuterProc2 AS

     BEGIN TRANSACTION

     INSERT INTO TABLE1 
     VALUES('Data from OuterProc code')

     EXEC usp_my_procedure_name 

     COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If you then run the procedure:

```
EXEC OuterProc2;
```

The inner procedure error is returned to the caller:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_my_procedure_name, Line 36
>   [Batch Start Line 54] usp_my_procedure_name: 8134: Divide by zero
>   error encountered.

But the  `Data from OuterProc code` string is still inserted.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1;

Value
Data from OuterProc code
```

If you do not use a savepoint, then the entire transaction will be rolled back.
As a result, errors will occur when trying to COMMIT the non existing tran.

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_my_procedure_name, Line 0
>   [Batch Start Line 53] Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a
>   mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1,
>   current count = 0. Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OuterProc2,
>   Line 10 [Batch Start Line 53] The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no
>   corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.